# PHP: delete the first line of a text and return the rest

Tags: php, string

What's the best way to remove the very first line of a text string and then echo the rest in PHP?

For example.

This is the text string:

```
$t=<<<EOF
First line to be removed
All the rest
Must remain
EOF;
```

This is the final output:

```
All the rest
Must remain
```

If I was working with a file in Bash I could do easily the next:

`sed -i~ 1d target-file`

Or:

`tail -n +2 source-file > target-file`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

How about preg_replace:

```
$text = "First line.\nSecond line.\nThird line.";
echo preg_replace('/^.+\n/', '', $text);
```

This way you don't need to worry about the case where there is no newline in your file.
http://codepad.org/fYZuy4LS

Comment: It all depends and it's a nice alternative for other solutions

Comment: Note that since you use a greedy quantifier and the `.` (which matches all characters), you will get **only the last line**, not everything except the first line. You should make the quantifier reluctant, i.e: `/^.+?\n/`

Comment: @PatrikAkerstrand Dot doesn't match `\n`, so that is not the case.

Comment: preg makes code less maintainable since a lot of marginal (and experienced) programmers don't understand it.

Comment: @ComFreek: It's turns out `preg_replace` in PHP isn't that slow, I benchmarked all solutions from all answers here: http://codepad.org/xt9kK2E2

Answer (score 50):

In alternative to the other answers with either `explode` & `implode` or regular expressions, you can also use [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/function.strpos.php) and [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/function.substr.php):

```
function stripFirstLine($text) {        
  return substr($text, strpos($text, "\n") + 1);
}
echo stripFirstLine("First line.\nSecond line.\nThird line.");
```

Live example: http://codepad.org/IoonHXE7

Comment: +1 You got this in just before I finished adding the same thing to my answer.

Comment: Your live speedtest example from codepad contains a severe bug. In the second run your `$n` is not initialized correctly. It must be: `$n = $count;`
Instead of 6x times faster it's "only" 2x times faster.

Comment: @Jan Thanks for noticing! Nine years later I am also aware of the pitfalls of microbenchmarking. I removed the note on performance now.

Answer (score 9):

`explode()` it on the line breaks into an array, `shift()` off the first line, and rejoin the rest.

```
$arr = explode("\n", $t);
array_shift($arr);
echo implode("\n", $arr);

// Prints
// All the rest
// Must remain
```

If your string is really large, this will use a lot of memory.  But if your strings are comparable to your example, it will work fine.

Method 2, using `strpos()`

```
echo substr($t, strpos($t, "\n") + 1);
```

Answer (score 7):

I know it's a late answer, but why wouldn't you just use an explode and limit the number of results

```
$parts = explode("\n", $test, 2);
//$parts[0] has the first line
//$parts[1] has everything else
```

Answer (score 2):

More flexible solution where you can remove ***num*** lines from a string ***str*** using a ***seperator*** and return the rest.
The default ***seperator*** is `\n`. If you want to use a different ***seperator*** use a third argument when calling `striplines()` function.

```
function striplines($str,$num,$seperator="\n"){
    $arr = explode($seperator, $str);
    for ($i=0;$i<$num;$i++) array_shift($arr);
    return implode($seperator, $arr);
}

//Testcases to remove first two lines
// returns/prints only Third line
echo striplines("First line.\nSecond line.\nThird line.",2); 

// returns/prints nothing
echo striplines("First line.\nSecond line.\n",2); 
echo striplines("First line.\nSecond line.",2);
echo striplines("First line.\n",2);
echo striplines("First line.",2);
echo striplines("",2);
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried all of these, and none seemed to work fast enough with large files (50MB+).  Here was the solution I created.  In your case, you could omit the echo of the first line.

```
$fh = fopen($local_file, 'rb');
echo "add\tfirst\tline\n";  // add your new first line.
fgets($fh); // moves the file pointer to the next line.
echo stream_get_contents($fh); // flushes the remaining file.
fclose($fh);
```

Answer (score 1):

Return a substring after the first newline-character:

```
$firstLineRemoved = $subject;
$firstNewlinePosition = strpos($subject, "\n");
if($firstNewlinePosition !== false)
{
  $firstLineRemoved = substr($subject, firstNewlinePosition +1);
}
echo $firstLineRemoved;
```

Edit: Same example as @ComFreek, but with error checking in case there is no new-line character

Answer (score 0):

All the answers are inefficient. There is no need to use any functions to manipulate the string.

```
$pos = 0;
while ($str[$pos] !== PHP_EOL)
    $str[$pos++] = '';
echo $str;
```

If you are not sure that the string always contains more than one line use this:

```
if (strpos($str, PHP_EOL))
{
    $pos = 0;
    while ($str[$pos] !== PHP_EOL)
        $str[$pos++] = '';
    echo $str;
}
```

Comment: @aefxx Of course I'm still manipulating the string. I never said I wasn't, I just said it's not necessary to use any functions to manipulate the string.

Comment: It really isn't necessary. However, where the benefit in learning arises is what is contained within the function. I typically yank the code out and inline the solution. Less overhead. Wrapping a solution enables learning different methods riddled throughout SO.